# Have 2 installations of firefox at same time

Tags: macos, firefox

How can I have 2 different versions of firefox exist and not interfere with one another?

The two version I want are:

- Latest, for normal use (sync with mobile, etc)
- v19, for compatibility with older software (doesn't work on newer versions, due to old ssl protocol errors) and will not be syncing or updating ever.

How can I have these coexist without much hassle?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just make one or both of them [a portable installation](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable).

Comment: Where can I find portable versions for Mac?  Somewhere between v15-v19.  All I can find are for windows.

Comment: Well, when I Google for `portable firefox mac`, the [first search result](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20395/portable-firefox) is Version 4.0.1r4.1, so I am not sure about version numbers. I guess that you just have to search